# why is the private member function of inherited class getting executed?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I want to know the logic behind how are we getting access to the private member function in Child class.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Parent{
public:
    virtual void secret(){};
};

class Child:public Parent
{
    string name;
    void secret(){
        cout << "Cant Access this";
    }
public:
    Child(string name):name(name){}
};

int main()
{
    Child c("Whatever");
    Parent* ptr = &c;
    ptr->secret();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
*Cant Access this*

Regards,

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Comment: The accepted answer on that duplicate is a masterpiece written by a genius

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058) - Please read that. I wonder why that crap keeps showing up? Is there some websites or *bad* teaching material somewhere promoting that badness?  See also [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/5910058) - You are doing two things that are each bad and then combine them into a complete disaster.

Comment: Wow! thank you for the help! I shall read other articles also

Comment: The logic is that implementing the rules that it seems you are expecting would mean that the public or private nature of a virtual method would have to be stored and checked at runtime. At present this doesn't happen. I can't see any advantage to requiring this, and I guess the standards writers couldn't either.

Comment: Keep in mind that none of these comments will answer your question. I like this question, and the "simple-minded" answer is: Because you are accessing `Parent` semantics, the compiler will allow it. But I will stick around for a really good theoretic answer as to why it's allowed.

Comment: In `class Parent`, change the method to `private: virtual void secret(){}`, which should clear up the access mystery.  Also turn on your compiler warnings, and fix those.

Comment: @Andy "Keep in mind that none of these comments will answer your question" - That's why they are posted as *comments* rather than *answers* 

Comment: Probably comes down to the classic "Not worth the extra compiler complexity required to trap and prevent this."

Comment: @Andy It's hard to know why it wouldn't be. What result do you expect instead? What kind of error response?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings -- i guess you're right -- What he's doing is slightly unorthodox, which is why it caught me off guard. Got my brain working, that's for sure.

Comment: @Andy Yeah usually you'd just stick with the one access level :)